# How Static methods are mocked in any Mocking Framework like JMockit,PowerMocks?

Tags: java, mocking

I learnt that  we can mock static methods using core java library with PowerMock?Jmockit.Want to understand how it is doing it internally in brief?

My Understanding:- As we define the mock class in the test case itself(Though there are different ways to create mock class in every framework like using expectation syntax in Jmockit), these framework must be defining custom classloader thru which they must be looking for that class definition inside the testcase itself.**Its a Guess. Not sure if it is correct?** But even if i am right, preference of classloader hirerchy is boootstraploader then applicationclassloader than customerclassloader. **So how does it pick from customerclassloader instead of applicationclassloader ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JMockit and other newer frameworks are based on the Java 1.5 Instrumentation framework. This allows you to redefine private, static and final methods. Even no-arg constructors can be redefined.

These frameworks use Java agent which is a pluggable library that runs embedded in a JVM and intercepts the classloading process and can help to instrument the bytecode of the classes.

You can check Java instrumentation in deep and http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/about.html